# Github Modules Versioning Tag Reference Fails

Tags: git, terraform

Im using the latest v0.11.11, and am trying to use a module hosted in github that has tags e.g v1.1.0.  Ive tried a few combinations, and the doco isnt clear on this for github (or I missed it :).  Examples Ive tried:

```
source = "github.com/xxx/module_repo?ref=v1.1.0"
source = "git::https://github.com/xxx/module_repo.git?ref=v1.1.0"
```

then I do a:

```
terraform get -update && terraform init
```

and get the error below:

```
Updating source "git::https://github.com/xiatechs/sdv-terraform-aws-lambda.git?ref=v1.1.0"
Error loading modules: error downloading 'https://github.com/xxx/module_repo.git?ref=v1.1.0': /usr/local/bin/git exited with 1: error: pathspec 'v1.1.0' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Both examples fail with the same error message.

Ive tried deleting the .terraform so its fresh and still the issue.

Any ideas greatly appreciated! :)

Thanks!

Comment: Git is telling you that the tag/refspec doesn't exist so either it's correct and it doesn't exist or there's access permissions issues. Does it work if you use `ref=master`?

Comment: Hmm - yes it does.  Im so sorry to have wasted your time!  git push --tags : cant believe that was it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

add // after github.com
source = "git::[https://github.com//xxx/module_repo.git?ref=v1.1.0"](https://github.com//xxx/module_repo.git?ref=v1.1.0%22)

this solved the same issue for me ..  mat be this is helpfull